# Knockout: Selecting a subset of an array

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

I would like to create a knockout setup that will allow the user to select a subset of one list into another list.  I select items in the first list using jquery UI selectable.  When the selection runs, I push the data from the selected item into a second observable array.  I have a  tag which is bound to that second array, but it doesn't seem to update when I do the push.

Here's my code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css"></link>
<style>
.ui-selected
{
    border: 1px dotted red;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="knockout-2.3.0rc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init()
    {  
        function AppViewModel() 
        {
            this.cars = ko.observableArray(
            [
                {year: 2004, make: "Chevy", model: "Malibu"},
                {year: 1995, make: "Honda", model: "Civic"},
                {year: 2004, make: "Chevy", model: "Malibu"},
                {year: 1985, make: "Honda", model: "Civic"},                
                {year: 1984, make: "Chevy", model: "Malibu"},
                {year: 1960, make: "Ford", model: "Ram"}

            ]);
            this.selectedCars = ko.observableArray();
            this.test=ko.observable("Bob");
        }       
        ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
        $("#cars tbody").selectable(
        {
            filter: "tr",
            selected: function( event, ui )
            {
                var selectedCarRow = ui.selected;
                var bindingContext = ko.contextFor(selectedCarRow);
                var observableCarData = ko.dataFor(selectedCarRow);
                bindingContext.$parent.selectedCars().push(observableCarData.make); 
                //alert(bindingContext.$parent.selectedCars().length);
                //alert(bindingContext.$parent.test());                             
            }   
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

<table id="cars">
    <thead><tr><th>Year</th><th>Make</th><th>Model</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: cars">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text:year"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:make"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:model"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
 <ul data-bind="foreach:selectedCars">
   <li data-bind="text:$data"></li>
 </ul>
  <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

For the most part your code is correct. There is one small issue though. In the selectable `selected` function you write `bindingContext.$parent.selectedCars().push` this pushes the object into the standard array and not the observable array. To push into the observable array where these changes will fire knockout events you would drop the `()` on the array object.

```
bindingContext.$parent.selectedCars.push(observableCarData.make);
```

Example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n27QL/1/